# 2 system-performance reporting-tools (dstat, pcp) are proposed by apt - which package is "official"?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, performance, monitoring

When I try to run performance monitoring and reporting tool "dstat", I simply type

`dstat`

on the command line.
I don't have it installed.
Ubuntu 20.04 comes up with this output:

```
> dstat
# command output

Command 'dstat' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install dstat  # version 0.7.4-6, or
sudo apt install pcp    # version 5.0.3-1
```

Which package is "official"? Is `pcp` actually better? It has the higher  version number, whereas `dstat` is v`0.7`. - Or does pcp simply *include* dstat 0.7. but also includes a web frontend (or something like that)

Get some basic info about both tools:

`dstat`

```
apt info dstat | grep -A 2 Description:

Description: versatile resource statistics tool
 Dstat is a versatile replacement for vmstat, iostat and ifstat.
```

`pcp`

```
apt info pcp | grep -A 2 Description:

Description: System level performance monitoring and performance management
 Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) is a framework and services to
 support system-level performance monitoring and performance
```

**Update**: Meanwhile I have installed `dstat`. I still do not understand *why* Ubuntu proposes both packages, as equivalent alternatives (`or`).

Comment: Hello. From the info in your question it seems you need to install them both. They appear to work together. So I do not think one is better then the other. Install both as the message says.

Comment: Both packsges are "official". It's up to you to read the documentation and decide which is "better" for your particular use case.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/implementing-dstat-performance-co-pilot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/implementing-dstat-performance-co-pilot) and [this post](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dstat-is-now-pcp-performance-co-pilot/), pcp is a newly developed version of dstat with extended capabilities.

> Dstat is a beloved tool by many, and a staple when diagnosing system
> performance issues.  However, the original dstat is no longer actively
> developed. This poses an immediate problem for distributions like
> Fedora moving to a Python 3 stack, as it lacks a Python 3
> implementation (both the tool itself, and its many plugins).  It is
> also problematic in that the plugin system was relatively simplistic
> and in need of a significant redesign and rewrite to add new desired
> features.

Interestingly, [the current version of dstat for Ubuntu uses python3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/dstat) so it seems there are some inconsistencies between the Redhat and Ubuntu versions of dstat and it appears our version is not as outdated.

<sub>**EDIT: the following applies to 18.04 and it seems that dstat is included in 20.04, possibly using the `pcp dstat` command**</sub>

For 18.04, dstat is not included with pcp and the `pcp dstat` command produces the following error:

```
~$ pcp dstat
Cannot find a pcp-dstat command to execute
Please install pcp system tools package
```

I tried this with pcp installed and with both pcp and dstat installed. I'm pretty sure this is a dstat error and not an Ubuntu error. However, it is strange that, according to Ubuntu, pcp provides dstat on 18.04 when, apparently, it does not.

Comment: I even installed all the various extra pcp packages and I still get the same error.

Comment: According to the filelist the command is just named `dstat` in [the `pcp` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/pcp/filelist).

Comment: @muru Yeah, I saw that and I just compared this to 18.04 and I guess it's not included on 18.04 but is on 20.04. Currently, I don't have a way to test the `pcp dstat` command until I fire up a 20.04 box or get around to installing on my bedroom computer that I've been meaning to get around to.